# Drawing bitmap fast on ARM Cotex

Tags: stm32, c, graphics

I'm trying to blit an image with sprites, animated.
While drawing the animated sprite, I draw a background before the sprites. With the sprites, the game looks smooth and playable, with the background its getting very slow.

I'm using a 240*320 image.
I tried my best to optimize the code and that's what I have resorted to.

```
void  DrawSprite(sprite_ptr spr, uint8_t *fb)
{
    const uint16_t* data = (spr->num_frames > 1 ) ? spr->frames[spr->curr_frame] : spr->imgData;

    uint16_t spriteHeight = spr->height;
    uint16_t spriteWidth  = spr->width;
    uint16_t x = spr->x;
    uint16_t y = spr->y;  

    for (int i = 0; i < spriteHeight; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < spriteWidth; j++)  
        {
            uint16_t color = data[j];
            if (color != 0)
            {
                LCD_DrawPixel(fb,j + x , i + y, color);
            }
        }

        data+=spriteWidth;  
    }
}
```

MODIFIED CODE:

```
void  DrawSprite(sprite_ptr spr, uint8_t *fb)
{
      const uint16_t* data = (spr->num_frames > 1 ) ? spr->frames[spr->curr_frame] : spr->imgData  ;


      uint32_t spriteHeight = spr->height;
      uint32_t spriteWidth  = spr->width;
      uint32_t x = spr->x;
      uint32_t y = spr->y;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < spriteHeight; i++)
        {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < spriteWidth; j++) {
            uint16_t color = *data++;
            if (color != 0)
            {
                                 *(__IO uint16_t*) (fb + (2*((i+y)*BSP_LCD_GetXSize() + j + x))) = color;

            }
             }

        }
}
```

Still the frame rate is not acceptable

Comment: I don't know how much difference it makes (or even if it does), but you're doing arithmetic and comparisons with mixed data types. I'd change your loop variables and all 4 of the local sprite variables to the same type (and I'd probably use 'unsigned int').

Comment: Also, instead of indexing into `data` as an array, maybe you could dereference & post-increment the pointer like `color = *data++;` and you wouldn't need the `data+=spriteWidth;`.

Comment: I *think* it might be better to write internally in RAM onto a [framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) and then use some DMA/interrupt to move an entire frame in the buffer to the LCD. This way it will be easier to update the pixels that have changed.  - I am not experienced with ARM cortex so I can be 100% wrong. - Right now you are addressing each pixel on the LCD. I am *very certain* that there is a mode that allows you to write consecutively, meaning you address the first and then just feed the next pixel in a stream.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I have done that, and that was pretty fast, but I do want to know why its that slow on a fast ARM 180 MHz, which is pentium 2 equivlent and much better

Comment: @brhans thanks for your suggestions, but still have no idea why its slow...

Comment: How is the LCD connected?

Comment: Random access functions like LCD_DrawPixel will have to perform something like   offset=x+y*displayWidth; which will be expensive if done per pixel. Also calling a function per-pixel will cost some overhead. Is it not possible to get a base pointer to LCD memory and walk a pointer across it? I would be inclined to stick to data[j] as opposed to *ptr++. ARM CPUs have indirect memory loads with offset.

Comment: I modified the code based on the suggestions, still the frame rate drops to 15 FPS

Comment: As a first step all of this "(fb + (2*((i+y)*BSP_LCD_GetXSize() + j + x)))" can be moved outside the inner loop by changing the limits and step of the loops.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general programming question. Please ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: most stackoverflow people doesn't even know what an LCD is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BSP_LCD_GetXSize() can trivially be moved to outside the loop, but this may not be something that compiler can do, as we know its value will not change.

Can you combine the background and sprite drawing, then several optimisations become possible?
For example you can have an array of bits Ysize in length, that are set to 1 if a sprite occupies that line, otherwise zero, same thing for the X axis, then if a y axis 'there is a sprite somewhere on this line' bit is zero you can just use the DMA to blit the whole line from the background (Or even all the lines until you find a non zero in the Y axis presence flags), if the 'line has a sprite' bit is '1' then you cook the DMA off for the line up to the first sprite, and while the DMA engine is moving the background, do the sprite painting loop for the appropriate line, then cook off the DMA for the next bit of line and so on.
This particular approach only works optimally with am memory mapped screen.

Keeping a sorted list of sprites is helpful as it makes finding the one you need to work on quicker, this also lets you impose an ordering on the sprites so that something reasonable happens when two sprites overlap.

Keeping a ring of DMA control buffers is very useful as it means you don't need to stop rendering sprites while you wait for the DMA core to complete.

The DMA engine is your friend, slightly tricky to use sometimes, but you really want it doing the constant stuff in the background.

You really want to be painting to a in memory frame buffer, then  DMA blitting that to the screen during the "VBI" to avoid tearing, not always possible because you don't always have sufficient ram, but nice when you can pull it off.

There may be some useful stuff in the "Graphics gems" books, probably volume one or two, they are the bible for CPU based 2D stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace the call to LCD_DrawPixel with a simple write to a volatile global variable. If the speed improves dramatically then the problem is in LCD_DrawPixel rather than in your loop.

You are mixing signed (probably) 32-bit integers (i, j) and unsigned 16-bit integers (x, y) in your code, which may cause the compiler to perform unnecessary checking or conversions. The hardware datatype for a Cortex-M processor is a 32 bit integer, so I would recommend that **all** of the variables used for calculations in your inner loop (i, j, x, y) be declared as uint32_t.

You should also try different optimization settings for the compiler. Optimize this code for speed rather than size.

Comment: I modified the code, but it's still drops the frame rate to 15FPS
https://pastebin.com/FuYsDsA6

Comment: What happened when you replaced the call to LCD_DrawPixel?